# Is it possible to group in a select box in a bootstrap button group?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to group in a select box in a button group like this.

[image: what I want]

But it's ends up like this.

[image]

And this is the html I've tried.

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="asc"> asc
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="desc">desc
  </label>
  <div class="btn">
    <select class="form-control">
      <option>1</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make a button group like this?

#### Fiddle

I created a example in jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/fe26/uv020gdq/1/

Comment: can you share fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is the padding of the wrapping div with the `btn` class. I managed to get closer to your example by assigning the `btn` class directly to the select:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group" role="group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="asc"> asc
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="desc">desc
  </label>
    <select class="btn" style="border: 2px solid #ccc; border-left: none;">
      <option>1</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

EDIT: you can use the icons that come with bootstrap to display the up/down-arrows. You need javascript to change the value of your components when the user clicks on an arrow. I would not recomment such a setup since it is hardly possible to use the up/down-controls on a mobile device.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group" role="group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="asc"> asc
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="desc">desc
  </label>
  <div class="btn" style="border-top: 2px solid #ccc; border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;">
       1
  </div>
  <div class="control" style="display: inline-block; line-height: 1rem; padding: 0.2rem; border: 2px solid #ccc; border-left: none">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top"></span><br />
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I want to have button like select box like the image.